# How to change AMP-WP submission response message

Tags: json, wordpress, redirect, amp-html

I want to change this response message:
[response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2MkB.png)

I found this [documentation](https://amp-wp.org/documentation/playbooks/handling-form-submissions/) but i don't understand where i have to add this json code ?

Comment: Hi! Could you please link the documentation that you found and don't understand?

Comment: https://amp-wp.org/documentation/playbooks/handling-form-submissions/

Comment: any idea @anonymousacorn ?

Comment: Hey again, I looked into this some but came up short. I hope someone else came chime in with more info, but in the meantime, have you reached out to the plugin's support forum on wordpress.org?

Comment: yes nothing so far... :(